# How to get the path of image uploaded in HTML5 FileReader

Tags: html, filereader

I have used the following way to check out the upload path, but it did not work.

```
reader.onload = function (e) {
                console.log(e.target);
                }
```

But this does not show the actual path.

Comment: **More information** about for what do you want the path for.. I did some [Google](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=HTML5+FileReader&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-beta) and found a [link that might help](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/)

Comment: Can you show the complete code? The snippet doesn't indicate anything.

Answer (score 1):

Technically, you can't trace the actual path of the image you are trying to read using any technology because its a security concern.

Although there are workarounds for specific browsers but they cannot be trusted! In addition to these, the new HTML5 specification states that browsers will need to feed a Windows compatible fakepath into the `<input type="file">` field, ostensibly for backward compatibility reasons.

I am trying to understand the use case of your requirement because to handle the uploaded files, you need the content only and not the actual path of the file.